# Xcode stops few lines after breakpoint position

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging

I have following code:

```
- (void)myFunction {                      // line 1
    if (self.myProperty) {                // line 2
        return; // BREAKPOINT IS SET HERE // line 3
    }                                     // line 4
    self.myProperty = 10;                 // line 5
}
```

Taking upon consideration, my breakpoint is on `return` statement, I'd expect the code to stop if it enters that line. Instead, I can see debugger stop at `line 5`. How is that possible? How to turn it off? I want it to stop only if it evaluates `line 3` (after which it can't continue to `line 5`).

I don't have any other breakpoints set in code at the moment. (There are no exception breakpoints nor anything like that.)

Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: Are you changing the code without rebuilding and re-installing on the device? The code you see in Xcode may not match what is compiled and on the device (or simulator).

Comment: I also thought about that, restarted everything and didn't make any changes. Still the same.

Comment: Even with non-optimized code it's not unusual to see the debugger current line indication "jump around" a bit.  That's simply the way the code gets compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot I've changed `build configuration` to `Release` ;). After setting it to `Debug` everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe place a breakpoint at line 2 to evaluate the contents of the conditional.  If self.myProperty has the value 0 it will always skip the return statement since 0 is equivalent to false.  Check to make sure self.myProperty has a different value or make your conditional more specific.

Comment: The value and the fact if is checked correctly is irrelevant to the issue. Either it enters or not. If it enters it should stop on return. If it doesn't enter it shouldn't stop. Anyway, found solution, posted below.